# Unable to iterate and pass down 'comments' as nested in a 'post' to component

Tags: reactjs, components, iteration, polymorphic-associations

I have 'comments' nested in a post called 'sightings' coming from Rails. I pass down the array of 'sightings' as a prop to `SightingContainer` and then to `SightingCard`. This all works fine. I then need to add the 'comments' (comments are commentable) in the same card. Right now I'm treating it as a separate branch from the App and sending an array of 'sightings' (has the comments nested) to `CommentsContainer` and then to `CommentsCard`. In `CommentContainer` i'm doing 2 iterations to drill down to 'comments'.

I'm a React newbie so I might not be implementing this correctly.

My `ComponentContainer` accepts the array `props.sightings`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Comment } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import CommentCard from '../components/CommentCard'


const CommentsContainer = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.sightings && props.sightings.map(sighting => {
      return  sighting.comments.map((comment, idx) => {
        return <CommentCard key={idx} comment={comment} editComment={props.editComment}
          likeComment={props.likeComment} addComment={props.addComment}  currentUser={props.currentUser} deleteComment={props.deleteComment}/>
      })
    })
    }
    </div>
  )
};

export default CommentsContainer
```

The error I get is:

```
×
←→1 of 3 errors on the page
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

If anyone can tell me a better way to implement this please advise!

Comment: Any help on this would be appreciated. No matter where I place the iteration through the nested items, I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that overall React does not do well with nested data. Much better to deal with it in the backend and send it up as un-nested data even if it has a `belongs_to` or polymorphic relationship.